# requestAnimationFrame runs twice as fast after cancelAnimtionFrame

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe, cancelanimationframe

I've been staring at my code for so long but i don't seem to understand what is happening.
Whenever the game ends, I do a cancelAnimationFrame to stop the game. Then I boot up the menu again.

Now the problem is that when I call requestAnimationFrame again, it seems like the code is calling it two times (the game runs doubly fast).

The following is my code:

This is the startup:

```
var areaJogo = {
    beginGame: function(type) {
        //...
        this.myReq = requestAnimationFrame(updateArea);
        //...
    }
}
```

And this is the main function(for animation):

```
function updateArea(){
    areaJogo.myReq=requestAnimationFrame(updateArea);

    //....

    if(/*conditionLoseGame*/) {
        stop();  
    }
}

function stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(areaJogo.myReq);

    areaJogo.myReq=undefined;
}
```

Mind you these are the only times requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame are used in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Use your debugger. Set a breakpoint in your `updateArea` function and inspect the stack-trace to see who is calling it a second time and why. Also, don't call `requestAnimationFrame` at the start of your function, instead call it before you return from it so you don't need to call `cancelAnimationFrame`.

Comment: The debugger seems to just say it's being called only from `updateArea` and the reason being because it's... well being called there. I've also tried changing the positions of `requestAnimationFrame` and the returns plus the `cancelAnimationFrame` but it seems that it remains the same unfortunately

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

The reason why it was being called is because I had done a button in JavaScript to start the game.

To do this, I had to do a addeventlistener whenever I booted the menu. What I did wrong was forgetting to do cleareventlistener upon clicking the button.